# Qual a origem da palavra "cueca"?

Tags: etimologia

Fiz uma busca pela tradução de cueca em outros idiomas europeus, a procura de alguma semelhança, e eis o que encontrei:

- Em espanhol-    calzoncillos
- Em francês:     slip
- Em italiano:    mutande
- Em Catalão:     calçotets
- Em Inglês:      underpants,
- Em Alemão:      Unterhose
- Em Galego:      calzóns

Não encontrando nenhuma palavra semelhante, pergunto se a origem de "cueca" não está relacionada à parte do corpo humano com a qual ela fica em contato direto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, tens razão. [O Primeram](https://dicionario.priberam.org/cueca) diz que vem de *cu* mais *‑eta*:

> **Origem etimológica**: *cu* + *‑eca*.
>
> "cueca", in *Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa* [em linha], 2008–2023, https://dicionario.priberam.org/cueca.

É como se fosse chamado de "buttlet" em inglês. :)

Comment: A [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/cueca), o [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/cueca), o [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/cueca/) e o Houaiss afirmam o mesmo.